# I want to know IP address

Tags: contacts, network

I want to know IP address of my friend .It's possible without software? Could you tell me what I do and how to do

Comment: You didn't specify internal or external IP address, so I made some assumptions and posted an answer below.

Comment: Let's tighten the requirements up. You could call your friend and ask them, visit their house, set up a web site to track visiting IP address or a whole host of other techniques. It's hard to know how this relates to users of Apple products as written.

Answer (score 2):

1. `ifconfig` from a terminal command line will tell you the internal IP address. Type `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1` to remove a lot of the unneeded text.
2. If you want your external IP address, just go to `whatismyip.com` or to Google and type 'IP Address' to show your public IP.
3. You can also find your internal IP address by going to System Preferences | Network and viewing your current connection (either AirPort for wireless, or Ethernet for wired, typically). Your status should display the current IP address.